# Implementing cascading stored procedures in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server

How can I maintain transaction across cascading stored procedures?

I am using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Do you mean sp1 invoking sp2 or sp1 doing something that causes a trigger cascade?

Comment: yes,it is similar to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the whole thing in a transaction, and it will work, but you HAVE to make sure that ALL your child/nested stored procedures will rollback the transaction, otherwise you will cause a deadlock. Something like this:

```
Create procedure [dbo].[parent] 
as
Begin Transaction
Begin Try
    Exec Child
End Try
Begin Catch
    If @@Trancount > 0
        RollBack
End Catch
Commit 


Create procedure [dbo].[Child] 
as
Begin Transaction
Begin Try
    --Do inserts here
End Try
Begin Catch
    If @@Trancount > 0
        RollBack
    RAISERROR('Error Occured',16,1)
End Catch
Commit
```